# ruby 2.0 named parameters from a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

If I have a method in ruby that takes named arguments...

```
def smoosh(first: nil, second: nil)
    first + second
end
```

Whats the easiest way to pass a hash to that method if the keys match:

```
params = { first: 'peanut', second: 'butter' }

smoosh(params)
```

The above produces an argument error.

### Update:

It seems like this might be an issue with how Sinatra parameters work.

When I do:

```
get 'a_sinatra_route' do
  hash = params.clone
  hash.symbolize_keys!

  smoosh(hash)
end
```

It works fine. It does not work when just passing the params in by themselves. (even though you can access the individual params with the symbol key `params[:attr]`)

Comment: Please copy-paste your exact code, as what you have given should work.

Comment: Your code seems to work properly

Answer (score 13):

Seems to work just fine for me.

```
2.0.0p0 :007 > def smoosh(first: nil, second: nil)
2.0.0p0 :008?>   first + second
2.0.0p0 :009?> end
 => nil
2.0.0p0 :010 > params = { first: 'peanut', second: 'butter' }
 => {:first=>"peanut", :second=>"butter"}
2.0.0p0 :012 > smoosh(params)
 => "peanutbutter"
```

Answer (score 11):

If your function is using keyword arguments, you'll need to use ** (double splat). [The ** (introduced in Ruby 2.0)](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/) acts like the original * operator, but can be used with Hashes (see also: [another good resource](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rubys-splat-and-double-splat-operators-ceb753329a78/)):

```
def smoosh(first: nil, second: nil)
  first + second
end

params = { first: 'double', second: 'splat' }    

smoosh(**params)
=> "doublesplat"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in ruby 2 but not in ruby 3 as hash are no more converted into keyword arguments.

Answer (score -7):

It's throwing an ArgumentError because you're passing in *one* hash to a method that takes two arguments - even though the hash has two key/value pairs, it's still just one argument!

In this situation, you can try:

```
smoosh(params[:first], params[:second])
```

To pass in the values.

Comment: I think you are confused by the question. It refers to named arguments, a Ruby 2.0 feature.